# How to implement refining conflict in constraint programming

Tags: python, constraint-programming, docplex

I use Docplex with python 3.7 to implement constraints programming. when it was infeasible, how can i proceed to list constraints those was to source of the conflict?

```
mdl.export_as_cpo(out="/home/..../MCP3.lp")
msol = mdl.solve(FailLimit=700000, TimeLimit=1600)
DInfos= msol.get_solver_infos()
mconflict=msol.CpoRefineConflictResult()
mconflict.get_all_member_constraints()
```

Error message:
mconflict=msol.CpoRefineConflictResult()
AttributeError: 'CpoSolveResult' object has no attribute 'CpoRefineConflictResult'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`solve` returns a `SolveResult`, and `CpoRefineConflictResult` is a class in `docplex.cp.solution`. So, the error message is correct: a `SolveResult` does not have an attribute `CpoRefineConflictResult`. You'd expect the `CpoRefineConflictResult` as the result of the conflict refiner.

You should probably read through the documentation a bit more http://ibmdecisionoptimization.github.io/docplex-doc/cp/docplex.cp.solution.py.html

You can call the `.refine_conflict()` method on the `CpoSolver` object to obtain a `CpoRefineConflictResult`, as documented here http://ibmdecisionoptimization.github.io/docplex-doc/cp/docplex.cp.solver.solver.py.html#detailed-description

Perhaps you can provide a minimal, reproducible example, if you need a more specific solution to your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks for this clarification, i have read the documentation and now my question is how to invoke the conflict refiner ?

Answer (score 0):

I have add:

```
from  docplex.cp.solver.solver import CpoSolver
```

After, i have add those lines if the model is infeasible:

```
mconfl= CpoSolver(model)
mconf = mconfl.refine_conflict()
```